# Post method returns code 302 Laravel but not When removed verifycsrftoken

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, laravel-5

I have started a project in **Laravel 5.2**. I pushed code on server then trying to login and it is getting redirected to login page with **`Status Code: 302 Found`**. The same code is working on Local.

Comment: Put your code, need to check how to ask on stackoverflow

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have solved that issue. next time before asking will surely check and post code too.